# StringIndex OutOf Bounds Exception

Tags: java

i am trying to find out the number of characters that exist in every string in an array
so i write this code . it doesn't work and getting error in the line

```
char c = a.charAt(0);
```

it seems that there is an empty string passing to the method so it throws this exception but i don't know how to fix that and make the code work
what should i do to fix it?
this is the code:

```
public class Gem_Stones {
    public static int counter = 0;
    public static int result = 0;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = Integer.parseInt(c.nextLine());
        String [] Gem = new String[N];
        for(int i =0; i<N ; i++){
            Gem[i] = c.nextLine();
        }
        solv(Gem[0] , subArr(Gem));
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static String [] subArr(String [] input){
        String [] ans = new String[input.length - 1];
        for(int i =0 ; i<ans.length ; i++){
            ans[i] = input[i+1];
        }return ans;
    }

    public static void solv(String a , String [] str){
        char c = a.charAt(0);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<str.length ; i++){
            if(contain(c , str[i]))
                counter++;
        }

        if(counter == str.length){
            result++;
            solv(sub(a) , str);
        } else {
            solv(sub(a) , str);
        }
    }

    public static String sub(String input){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
        sb = sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }

    public static boolean contain(char c , String s){
        for(int i=0 ; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i) == c)
                return true;
        }return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: what is the scanner input?

Comment: Have you debugged your application. It can be that your string is empty

Comment: As per @VD', the input appears to have a blank line. What is the input?

Comment: the input is an array of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check if the string is empty before you make any operation (and also to check if is null)

```
if(a == null || a.equals("") ){
  return null; //or throws an exception or -1 or anything you want to  do when a is empty
}

char c = a.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the string for isEmpty() befor charAt(0), just return if true.

Comment: i checked them with if(a == null || a.equals("") ) , and it help , thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is trying to find out the number of characters that exist in every string in an array, then you are doing a lot of unnecessary steps such as deleting characters.

Consider using a nested for loop:

```
public static int solve (String[] strings, char target) {
  int count = 0;

  for (String s : strings) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      if (target == s.charAt(i)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: this method work , but not doing exactly what i want

Comment: for example if the input was "aaa" , "abc" , "oia" the result is 5 for it is counting every "a" there . but the result must be 1 cause only one character "a" exist in every single string here . thanks :) .

Comment: I see. In that case I would suggest the following algorithm. First find the shortest word in the array. Then using a nested for loop, iterate over the characters in the short string on the outside and the string array on the inside. Keep track of the count which is initialized to short string.length(), and check if each string contains that character. If it does not, then count-- and break. Lastly account for duplicate characters in the short string. You really want to avoid removing characters from the strings.